# Generate Vue Project Using Open Api CLI Generator

Tags: .net-core, vuejs2, openapi, openapi-generator

I am working on a .net core 7.0 project. Now I want to create front-end project using Vue and  open api cli generator. I have installed open api generator cli using below command:

```
npm install -g @openapitools/openapi-generator-cli
```

I also ran the below command to generate the Vue project using my openapi.yaml file. Below is the command for the same:

```
openapi-generator-cli generate -i C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Temp\openapi.yaml -g vue -o my-project
```

However, it gives me below error:

```
Can't load config class with name 'vue'
[error] Check the spelling of the generator's name and try again.
```

Can I generate vue project using open-api or is there any other option to generate Vue project using swagger or open api?

Comment: Here's the [list of generators](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators) supported by OpenAPI Generator. There's no `vue`, but maybe another one (e.g. one of the `javascript*` or `typescript*` generators) will suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you @Helen for your response. I am wondering if the below link might help. What do you think?
https://api-platform.com/docs/create-client/vuejs/

Comment: I haven't used https://api-platform.com myself. It's up to you to see if that one works for you!